# I have an app written in C/C++ that needs to run every time system boots / restarts. What is the easiest method to achieve this?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, broadcastreceiver

All,
  I have a simple command line app that I have written using NDK. This app is written in C. I need to run this every time my Android device boots up. The device is running Android 7.

I am looking for the easiest way of achieving this. Do I have to write an Android app for this?. In the linux days, I could just add it to init.rc or some other method or start as a daemon and be done with it.

I have already tried writing an Android service that I build as an APK. This android service uses BroadCastReceiver to subscribe to BOOT_EVENT_COMPLETED. The service's onCommandStart() gets called at which point I invoke a JNI method to call system() with the path of my executable. I think the system() call is failing because the app does not have root permissions.

I know the service starts because I have Log.v() calls and I can see in the Logcat. I know the JNI method gets invoked because the same JNI method returns a string which I use as the title of the Android app window and that works.

If I run my app from adb shell by doing adb root followed by adb shell /data/ that works too

I just need to run the native app whenever system boots or reboots for whatever reason.

===============================================================================
Here is the output of ls -l on the app when run from adb shell. The app is in /data

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19512 2019-06-08 14:12

Here is the code for the Android app. 
By the way, the broadcastReceiver's OnReceive() does not get invoked either.

This is the code for the MainActivity.java. This is the activity.  I just added the call to JNI method here. This gets invoked as the string is returned by the C++ method which is used in the title. THis works. The call to run the app is also in the C++ method which is at the end

```
package com.rk.startonboot;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.util.*;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));

        Log.d("RKService", "RKService");

        // Example of a call to a native method
        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
        tv.setText(stringFromJNI());
    }

    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    public native String stringFromJNI();
}

This is the code for the service. I was planning to use this to call the C++ method eventually

package com.rk.startonboot;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.*;

public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //TODO write your own code

        Log.v("RKServiceLog", "RKServiceLog");

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        //TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
        return null;
    }
}

This is the code for the receiver

package com.rk.startonboot;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.*;

public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //TODO write your own code

        Log.v("RKServiceLog", "RKServiceLog");

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        //TODO for communication return IBinder implementation
        return null;
    }
}

This is the manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="com.rk.startonboot">

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.rk.startonboot.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
            android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the C++ code.

## include

## include

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_rk_startonboot_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string hello = "Hello from LedStrip";
    system("/data/ledstrip");
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}

Comment: And what happens when you give the app root permissions? It's hard to speculate where the problem might be when you post **no** code.

Comment: Can you please add a  log to check whether your app has executable permission?

Answer (score 0):

This can be NON ROOTED!

Try using Auto-Start in the google playstore. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.autostart

It is very easy to understand as well.  If you want more, go to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98276/open-an-app-on-startup-after-booting) page.